# Prevent Samsung S4 Screen From Turning on Every SMS

Tags: sms, screen, samsung-galaxy-s-4

How do you prevent the Samsung S4 screen from coming on with every SMS message that is received?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Stop from Samsung Galaxy S4 turning on when receiving text message](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/52792/11343).

Answer (score 1):

In the galaxy S4 SMS application, go to Settings and there is an option called "Screen On". Untick this option and you should be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I’m puzzled. Why do you want this behaviour?

Anyhow, I do not think it is possible. Mobile phones have been doing this as a way to silently alert you of activity since foerver.

If you want to preserve battery life, you can try dimming the screen as low as it can go instead.

Comment: The Galaxy Nexus does this by default and it is awesome (it lights up a tiny low power LED at the bottom of the phone instead). The screen is the largest power consumer on a device, if my phone already made a sound and vibrated, why do I need my screen on for 20-30 seconds to alert me even more and waste power? Yes it is a small amount but it is also completely unnecessary to do it too IMO.

Comment: Aeyoun, Adam is speaking about incoming text messages -- not incoming calls. A sound/vibrate info is sufficient for those, as it's no real-time communication. For incoming *calls* that's something different. I cannot remember having had any phone that turned on the display on incoming SMS. Should that be because I do not get so many SMS?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only affect texts, but leave other notifications alone, then go to your messaging app (the screen with all your threads, not a specific conversation), click the menu button > settings  go down to notifications and deselect "notifications".

If you're trying to get your phone to not react at all when you receive a notification, then Blocking Mode is your obvious answer. No noise, vibration, the screen stays off... you can even set it to not blink the notification LED.

I'm sorry if neither of those satisfy the outcome you're looking for, but that's really all that you can do to keep the screen from lighting up.