# Stop from Samsung Galaxy S4 turning on when receiving text message

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, samsung-touchwiz

**Summary**: Is there a way to stop the Samsung Galaxy S4 screen from turning on when receiving text messages (without disabling the notification light)?

**Details**:

I've got a Samsung Galaxy S4 on Verizon.  I've noticed that sometimes when it's in my pocket that it will turn on and access apps, etc. (for example one time I saw it had posted something to Facebook).

I think that the problem is when I receive a text message that the phone turns on and then from there the touch screen might do whatever it wants.  The reason I think the phone screen turns on when I receive a text message is I've noticed that happen sometimes.

So really what I want to do is prevent the phone from turning on in my pocket, but I don't think that is an actual option.  But I thought there should be a way to stop incoming text messages from turning on the screen, while still allowing the notification light to flash.  But I haven't found an option that does that.

Comment: No everything is totally stock.  I just got the phone less than a month ago and the only think I've done is install some apps.  Thanks for the comment, I might talk to Verizon tech support about it sometime.

Comment: Looks like I'm not the only one who has this problem, so I guess it is a stock setting from Verizon: https://community.verizonwireless.com/thread/804529

Comment: Duplicate of: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46752/prevent-samsung-s4-screen-from-turning-on-every-sms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like having the screen turn on when SMS messages arrive is a stock feature of the Samsung Galaxy S4 on Verzion (possibly applies to other models and carriers as well).  I saw threads [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=28756458) and [here](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s4/275943-does-your-s4-light-up-when-you-receive-text-email.html) discussing the problem.  There is no setting to disable only the screen turning on.

The workaround that I ended up using is as follows:

1) Disable notification in the stock app: go to settings and scroll down to Notification settings and unselect "Notifications".

[image]

2) Install [SMS Popup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.everythingandroid.smspopup&hl=en).

3) Enable SMS Popup.  Then go to Addition Settings and disable "Screen on for Popup".

[image]

Maybe someday Samsung/Verizon will fix the problem, but for now this workaround seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In the galaxy S4 SMS application, go to Settings and there is an option called "Screen On". Untick this option and you should be able to do what you want.